# ASP.NET Core modify heads on exception

Tags: asp.net-core

If I throw a `BadLabUpdateException` then I'd like the response headers of the request to include the exception details.  I tried to do this in my `Configure` method:

```cs
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp => {
    errorApp.Run(async context => {
        var pathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        if (pathFeature is BadLabUpdateException ex) {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Display-To-User", new StringValues(ex.Message));
        }
    });
});
```

That doesn't have any effect though.

The goal is essentially if I throw that specific exception from the server, then the message will contain the exact string that the client should display to the end user.

I need this to work both in development mode and production.

Comment: Personally I would prefer an approach based on an exception filter as explained  in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0#exception-filters

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: The downside to an exception filter is that it only applies to MVC and it doesn't run for "resource filters, result filters, or MVC result execution". The guidance in the docs is to use exception filters only "where error handling _differs_ based on which action method is called".

Comment: @KirkLarkin Do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: Sure. You've almost got it. It should be `if (pathFeature.Error is BadLabUpdateException ex)`.